# Siddhi App > Cassandra Extension: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or class path

Tags: java, cassandra, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm new to WSO2 streaming integrator. I'm using Ubuntu 20.* with OpenJDK version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 as Java is the back-end of WSO2 SI.

I'm creating a Siddhi app in which I'm trying to access Cassandra database using Siddhi App extension. By default this extension is not provided and so I installed it. After successfully installation of extension, when I write code for accessing Cassandra database as following

```
@store(type='cassandra' , cassandra.host='127.0.0.1:9042', username='cassandra', password='cassandra',keyspace='test',
column.family='test')
define table test (name string, amount double);
```

I face the following error:

> Cannot find a cassandra configuration for the keyspace testError in processing Cassandra query configuration:  Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or class path

I googled a lot to resolve the issue. Many answered that I've to add JAXB-API dependencies but I don't know how as I never worked on Java ever. I tried to find the way of implementation of JAXB-API, but did not reach a proper solution of implementation.

Could please someone help me to resolve the issue? Many appreciation will be for them.

### Addition in question

It is being to clarify that the Cassandra database is running successfully, and so there is no issue with running Cassandra database from terminal or using any UI.

Comment: Could you please share your pom.xml (or gradle prop)?

Comment: That's the problem. I'm not able to find where is pom.xml located?
If you say, I can update question with WSO2-SI tree.

Comment: Are you using the extension defined in https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-store-cassandra/ ?

Comment: Yes, I installed the extension using the extension installer.

Comment: I fix this issue by replacing Java v 11 with Java v 8.